# Mat::convertto() not working in javacv, android camera

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I am developing an Android OpenCV app based on Opencv4android SDK tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing.

in the frame processing function `public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {}`

The frame is RGBA and I want to make RGB by doing this:

```
 mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
 mGray = inputFrame.gray();

 Mat    mRgb=new Mat(640,480,CvType.CV_8UC3);
 mRgba.convertTo(mRgb, CvType.CV_8UC3);
 //Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgb, CvType.CV_8UC3);
 PinkImage(mRgb.dataAddr());
```

But when I debug and log the things I passed to the JNI part, I find it's not working at all.
`mRgb` is `CV_8UC4` even after calling `converto()`

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the answer is [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17528/matconvertto-not-working-in-javacv-tutorial-2/?answer=17530#post-id-17530)

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,mRgb,Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
```

instead of

```
mRgba.convertTo(mRgb, CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You never use the converted data. You still pass `mRgba.dataAddr()` to `PinkImage()`, which is the unmodified RGBA image. You need to pass in the modified data:

```
PinkImage(mRgb.dataAddr());
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's just a typo. I Debug and gets still 4 channel mRgb even after the change.  And I use C++ interface inside jni and gets still the same thing. I guest the MatFrame data is somehow, not allowed to change.